# Is Hashing a Data Structure or Hash Table is a Data Structure?

Tags: data-structures

In Data Structure and Algorithm,

I am confused if Hashing is a Data Structure or Hash Table is a Data Structure or If Hashing and Hash Table both are Data Structures?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to look at the parts of speech. Hashing is a gerund or present participle, built from the verb "hash". Both a hash table and a data structure are nouns.

Hence a "hashing" (participle, though prefixing it with "a" is no doubt poor form) cannot be a data structure (noun)<sup>(a)</sup>. The hash table, which is a table of hashed entries with other information as required, is a data structure.

Hashing is the act of taking input data, performing some hash function on it, and returning the result of that.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It makes about as much sense to state that a jumping is an ice-cream :-)